# Different Results Between MySQL and PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

Locally I use MySQL and remotely I use PostgreSQL (on Heroku) and I'm getting different results.

controller

```
 @customer = current_customer
 @shows = @customer.shows
 @musicals = Musical.find(:all, :conditions =>['show_id in (?)', @shows])

 @musicals.each do |musical|
   @musical_activities = Activity.where('musical_id in (?)', musical.id).count(:group => "activity_type_id")
 end
```

view

```
<table>
  <tr>
<th>Activity</th>
<th>Number</th>     
  </tr>

<% @activities.each do |activity_id, count| %>
  <tr>
<td><%= activity_description(activity_id) %></td>
<td><%= count %></td>
  </tr>  
<% end %>
</table>
```

Previously, I had used = instead of in, but I changed it because I was getting a PGError saying that argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type record.  Whether I use = or IN, I get the correct results locally.

When I run it on Heroku, and replace = with IN, the error goes away, but the result is wrong.  I simply get one row where the first column (activity_description) is blank and instead of showing me the counts by activity types, the count is either aggregated or only only one activity_type is showing.  I.e., only one row appears even though I have many activity_types and the one row didn't return the activity_id.

Comment: This is a good reason why you should (when possible) use the same dbms across your environments

Answer (score 1):

When you migrate your database to Heroku, Heroku internally uses the `taps` gem to import your local DB to Heroku.
But, there are some constraints to it(foreign keys and Postgres Bigint).

[Taps gem constraints when importing local DB to Postgres](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/taps#constraints)

If, this doesn't help you, here are some great links to help you with the conversion.

1. [Converting Rails application data from MySQL to PostgreSQL](http://pivotallabs.com/users/jpignata/blog/articles/1077-converting-rails-application-data-from-mysql-to-postgresql)
2. [Rake task to transfer a Rails database, say from MySQL to Postgres and back again](http://myutil.com/2008/8/31/rake-task-transfer-rails-database-mysql-to-postgres)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use the ClearDB mySQL addon (http://addons.heroku.com/cleardb) and remain on mySQL.